# htacess with Get URL parameters on all pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using a custom framework which will take PHP extension and convert to HTML which is parsed out with templating engine. I am using an htaccess which is working great. However when I introduced a GET URL parameter (on any page), it throws a 404 error. All requests are funnelled through the bootstrap.php page, then routed and processed.

Here is my htaccess:

```
# this funnels every request through the bootstrap unless the request includes a specific file or document
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(js|css|errors|images|fonts|media)
   RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|ttf|eot|svg|woff|GIF|pdf)$ bootstrap.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ bootstrap.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried the following:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?p=$1 [QSA, L]
```

And also tried

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

And am still getting a 404 error.

Comment: http://localhost.local/configure.html?id=5

Comment: Yes, localhost.local/foobar?id=5 gives a 404 error

Comment: It works for me. You shouldn't need to extract - append or use `QSA` because you're not touching the querystring. Have you tried adding a RewriteBase? Next step, if you haven't already done it, I would set loglevel to rewrite:trace6 and check the error log to find what the server thinks is the exact path of bootstrap.php after rewrite.

Comment: the htaccess is indeed working, I removed the comment character, saved the htaccess file,  and pulled it up in a browser with a 500 error

Comment: What is location of this `bootstrap.php` and `.htaccess` and what is your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: document root = /builder/ ; bootstrap.php and htaccess are both in this document root

Comment: Replace all of the shown code below `RewriteEngine on` with `RewriteRule !bootstrap\.php$ bootstrap.php [NC,L]` and comment out `IfModule` lines